# How do I know, from the smartphone, which is the available port at the server?

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I'm trying to make a client/server app for my final assignment at school. What I'm trying to do is to connect my tablet/phone to my computer and send an audio file that the computer will analyse and then it will light up some LED's and stuff.

My problem is: I know how to connect a client to a server (with fixed ports) throw the sockets, but I would like to know which port is the server using, instead of putting a fixed port on the code(at the client).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `send an audio file that the computer`. Not to the computer but to a server program running on that computer. Well it depends on the server program which port it does use and which protocol. So which server application are you going to use?

Comment: I'm trying to make onde myself...

Comment: I'm trying to make an app in java (server). And one in android(client).

Comment: Why don't you want to use a fixed port?  That is the ordinary way.  You'll notice that things which can't (temporary FTP server on a phone or restricted user account) often end up displaying a port number which has to be manually entered into the client - an unusual and generally undesirable outcome.

Comment: So YOU are making a server and ask US which port it uses?

Comment: You can use [Network Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html). It's not trivial, but works quite well.

Comment: Usually you hit a known port then talk to a dynamic port afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really desired:
You could install web server (apache,ngix), modify your server app to write the port number it listens to in a publicly accessible file and fetch it from the client app via HTTP to figure out the port number that server listens to now.

Or just make another server app that would listen on port 80 and report back your custom port to the client as it connects.

Something has to be hard-coded, that's how client/server apps are working anyway, both has to know the protocol and end points.